# How can I determine if a string is part of an enum?

Tags: typescript

I have an enum and a string

```
enum Keys {
  'key1' = 'key1',
  'key2' = 'key2'
}

const key = 'key1'
```

Is there a way to check if `key` is part of the enum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the repetition of the term “key” it’s not clear to me whether you want to check the existence of the property (does Keys.key1 exist?) or the value (is there a property of Keys whose *value* matches “key1”).

To check for the existence of the property, use `Keys[key]` or `Keys.hasOwnProperty(key)`. The first is more concise but because it evaluates the *value* it will return false if the value is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) e.g.`Keys[key] === 0`.

```js
if (Keys[key]) {
  // exists with non-falsy value. do stuff.
}
```

```js
if (Keys.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
  // exists. do stuff.
}
```

To check for the presence of the value, you can use Object.values and Array.includes:

```js
if (Object.values(Keys).includes(key)) {
 // do stuff
}
```

Comment: `hasOwnProperty` actually won't check the value of the enum, it wil match the key. The fact that the example enum has the same key as a value is coincidental.

Comment: Yes. I know. That’s what I said.

Comment: Yeah, I see that. I would always recommend to use the value to map to. For example when you are getting an API response you'd want to match the value returned by it to the enum and use the key as a reference in your code.

Comment: The question was how to determine whether the key exists.

Comment: Updated with clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You can [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get the values of the enum and then use [.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to see if the value exists.

```
enum Keys {
    One = 'one',
    Two = 'two'
}

Object.values(Keys).includes('one') // true
Object.values(Keys).includes('foo') // false
```

I would also reccomend that you do not use the same name for the key as the value. It's conventional in TypeScript to use a pascal case name for your key.

Comment: thanks for the reply. do you know if there is a way to get the union type of the values from an enum? here it would be `one | two`,

Comment: `type SomeType = Keys.One | Keys.Two`

Comment: thanks for the reply but the compiler still suggests that the type is `type SomeType = Keys` instead of `one | two` here is the demo https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-rgb-u860z?file=/src/index.ts